# Changing text color with Swift

Tags: text, swift, colors, ios8, xcode6

I'd like to change the text color of a cell in my table view.
If i do this it's not working. In xcode6 beta 1 it works but on the final version of xcode6 it's not working.

Code:

```
cellGrow.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Error: `'textColor' is unavailable: APIs deprecated  as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is cellGrow a UITableViewCell? In that case use this:-

```
cellGrow.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: Yes, cellGrow is a UITableViewCell. It' works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure and thanks for marking as answer! I would also appreciate an upvote!