# How do I change the text color in Swift?

Tags: swift, indicator

I found the indicator function on Stackoverflow. I like it too, but I couldn't change the text color, actually, I change the code that is blackColor() but it doesn't work. How do I fix it? I want to see text and indicator are black.

```
class ProgressHUD: UIVisualEffectView {

    var text: String? {
        didSet {
            label.text = text
        }
    }
    let activityIndictor: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
    let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
    let vibrancyView: UIVisualEffectView

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        self.vibrancyView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect))
        super.init(effect: blurEffect)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.text = ""
        self.vibrancyView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect))
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.setup()

    }

    func setup() {
        contentView.addSubview(vibrancyView)
        vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(activityIndictor)
        vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(label)
        activityIndictor.startAnimating()
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        if let superview = self.superview {

            let width = superview.frame.size.width
            let height = superview.frame.size.height
            self.frame = CGRectMake(superview.frame.size.width / 2 - width / 2,
                superview.frame.height / 2 - height / 2,
                width,
                height)
            vibrancyView.frame = self.bounds

            let activityIndicatorSize: CGFloat = 50
            activityIndictor.frame = CGRectMake(5, height / 2 - activityIndicatorSize / 2,
                activityIndicatorSize,
                activityIndicatorSize)

            layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            layer.masksToBounds = true
            label.text = text
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.frame = CGRectMake(activityIndicatorSize + 5, 0, width - activityIndicatorSize - 15, height)
            label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor() //I changed here grayColor() to blackColor but it doesn't work!
            label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(16)
        }
    }

    func show() {
        self.hidden = false
    }

    func hide() {
        self.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: the text of what ? ?

Comment: This one: label.text = text

Comment: Okay I added an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing text color with Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423838/changing-text-color-with-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color:

```
label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

And ofc you can change to any color you want just by initialising a UIColor instance